# .NET Core API Problem using multiple authentication schemes

Tags: c#, api, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having some difficulty getting multiple authenticaion schemes to work with my .NET Core API.

Each works perfectly when set as the **Default Scheme** to be used, but I cannot get them to chain authenticaion, so if one fails authentication it moves onto the next one in the chain to try and authenticate using that scheme.

I'm using

- JWT Bearer Token Authentication
- API Key Authentication

As can be seen in the code below I've setup an **AuthorizeFilter** policy with the multiple schemes, but obviously I'm missing something somewhere along the way and I'm hoping you may be able to spot what I am missing.

Below is the complete start up code I am using.

Kind Regards

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
            {
                authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(bearerOptions =>
                    {
                        bearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                        bearerOptions.SaveToken = true;
                        bearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidIssuer = JWTProvider.CLAIM_ISSUER,
                            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(this.Configuration[JWTSecurityKeyProvider.DEFAULT_JWT_SECURITY_KEYNAME])) { KeyId = "416" },
                            ValidAudience = JWTProvider.API_AUDIENCE,
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                            ValidateLifetime = true,
                            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
                        };
                    })
                .AddApiKeySupport(options =>
                {
                });
            services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                var defaultSchemes = new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme };
                var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(defaultSchemes)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Auth API", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddSingleton<JWTSecurityKeyProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<JWTProvider>();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Auth API v1"));
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes):

> Only one JWT bearer authentication is registered with the default authentication scheme JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme. Additional authentication has to be registered with a unique authentication scheme.

Also it rewrites default policy in `services.AddAuthorization()` insted of `services.AddControllers()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it actually registers multiple Authentication schemes when it adds in the AuthorizePolicy.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else experiences this issue, to sort out the problem you need to include the Authorized Schemes as an attribute on each controller. Then everything is works tickety-boo.

E.g.

```cs
   [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme)]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : BaseAuthenticatedController
    {
```